# How to go to cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have these characters but I want to go to cycles but when I do the characters goes grey and purple. (Essentially The textures get removed from the character(s). Is there a way to switch to cycles without losing the textures?

I will leave one of the characters as a example. So can I go to cycles and keep textures?
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mb2by9y7d91q2t2/AACvhUDp_MZ7ZKHchibT9tlYa?dl=0

-Thanks!

Comment: I believe you will need to recreate all of the materials/textures.

Answer (score 0):

there is one node in cycles that will solve most of your problems: the principled shader. it is the nearest your will come to the material system of blender render.

theck this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck